# Problema con ng-repeat, mal comportamiento al aplicar filtros

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Al presentar una colección de objetos, necesito establecer un límite de 8 entradas. Lo cierto es que usando `limitTo:8` angular hace cosas raras y me trae siempre una cantidad errada y distinta a la que yo quiero, además hace mal el `orderBy`.

```
ng-repeat="item in Items| filter:{tipo:'tipo'} | orderBy:'micriterio' | limitTo:8"
```

Existe alguna "regla" que indique el orden en el que se deben aplicar estos filtros?.

Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, incluye una muestra de los datos y del criterio de búsqueda.

Comment: Es una coleccion que lista items y debe filtrarse por un campo que tiene dos valores "Pre" o "Pro" , a su vez debe ordenarse por País. Estas dos funcionalidad estan correctas, el error se da unicamente al aplicar el "limitTo:"

Comment: @JoaquínPiñeyro El orden es correcto, Me parece raro que no funcione como debería. Mira cómo funciona [este codigo](http://jsbin.com/quwanereka/edit?html,js,output) similar al tuyo.

Comment: Si muestras tu datos y criterio podemos ayudar mas. A mi el orden es correcto y el codigo debe funciona sin problema. Mira este ejemplo en JSFiddle: [ejemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/wrobe0709/8pnjbdqk/2/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Al fin y al cabo el problema era porque tenia un ng-show con una logica bastante complicada, lo que hice fue hacer esa lógica en un método del controlador y que éste sea el **primer filtro** de mi colección.
Gracias por las respuestas!

Comment: Si estás usando `ng-show` para ocultar porque no usar `ng-if` y dejas el filtro como está. Así tu programa es fácil de leer y cualquiera puede entender la lógica de lo que quisiste escribir en lugar de crear una solución rebuscada.

Answer (score 1):

Debes entender una cosa sobre los filtros de angular: *¡¡¡el orden importa!!!* y la regla es que estos se ejecutan en el mismo orden que se escriben de izquierda a derecha.

```
{{expresion | filtro1:parametro | filtro2:parametro | filtro3:parametro }}
```

Primero angular te **evaluará** la expresión, el resultado de esta evaluación será el la entrada de `filtro1`, el resultado de este procesamiento será la entrada de `filter2` y así sucesivamente mientras se encuentren filtros en la expresión completa.

Para que entiendas mejor esto te voy a escribir tu mismo filtro pero por partes, agregando un filtro más por cada `ng-repeat` para que compruebes los resultados de cada aplicación

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('CollectionCtrl', function($scope) {

    // collecione de datos
    $scope.collecion = [{
      nombre: 'Juan',
      tipo: 'persona'
    }, {
      nombre: 'Lassie',
      tipo: 'perro'
    }, {
      nombre: 'Pedro',
      tipo: 'persona'
    }, {
      nombre: 'Eduardo',
      tipo: 'persona'
    }, {
      nombre: 'Rintintin',
      tipo: 'perro'
    }, {
      nombre: 'Frank',
      tipo: 'persona'
    }];
  });
```

```css
hr {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="CollectionCtrl">
  <h3>Collecion completa</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="obj in collecion">
    {{obj.nombre}}
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h3>
    Collecion filtrada tipo: 'persona'
  </h3>
  <div ng-repeat="obj in collecion | filter: {tipo: 'persona'}">
    {{obj.nombre}}
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h3>
    Collecion filtrada y ordenada
  </h3>
  <div ng-repeat="obj in collecion | filter: {tipo: 'persona'} | orderBy : 'nombre'">
    {{obj.nombre}}
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h3>
    Collecion filtrada, ordenada y limitada a 2 resultados
  </h3>
  <div ng-repeat="obj in collecion | filter: {tipo: 'persona'} | orderBy : 'nombre' | limitTo: 2">
    {{obj.nombre}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Así que si no obtienes los resultados correctamente es quizás porque el filtro `filter` no lo tienes bien escrito o no te están llegando los datos correctamente ya que `orderBy` no cambia la cantidad de ítems obtenidos, solo `filter` y `limitTo` lo hacen. Este ultimo es un equivalente de algo como

```
var resultado = collecion.slice(0, cantidad);
```